# How to remove the last row of days in bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the date picker component http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
I'm trying to find a way to set the height or remove the last row of days so it's smaller in height.

Right now I'm getting a row of days that I don't need at the bottom.
I'd like to remove the entire bottom row from 30th - 5th so the height would become smaller when the user opens the calendar.
Anyone know anyway to achieve this. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the last row using CSS (you'll have to use the right datepicker class and index though, might not be 7):

```
.datepickerClass tr:nth-child(7) {
    display: none;
}
```

You should be able to update it when you click on the arrows (you could write something similar to this for the ".prev" button):

```
$(".datepickerClass .next").click(function () { 
    $(".datepickerClass tr:nth-child(7)").css("display","none");
});
```

Comment: But when you use the back and forward arrows this gets messed up. IS there no attribute setting for this.

Comment: It "gets messed up" doesn't say much... I just updated the code, I hope that helps